# welcome page before main page

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.1

I' using Symfony2.1 and I want to do something like this:

[Welcome page before main page](http://www.liverpoolfc.com/)

When user comes to my page / I want redirect him to /welcome. When he clicks on link, which is in the /welcome then he should be redirected to / page, but then he should see main page (/) not welcome page again. How can I do this with routing? Is it possible?

In "normal" PHP I do this with sessions, what about Symfony2?

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem with sessions like this:

I have two routes: core_homepage (pattern /) and welcome_homepage (pattern /welcome).

```
//Controller for core:
public function indexAction()
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        if ($session->get('welcome_flag')=='0'){
            return $this->render('MarkCoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
        } else {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('welcome_homepage'));
        }  
    }

//Controller for welcome:
public function indexAction()
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        if ($session->get('welcome_flag') == '0'){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('core_homepage'));   
        } else {
            $session->set('welcome_flag', '0');
            return $this->render('MarkWelcomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

If anybody has any other - solutions please post.

Comment: It is best if instead of managing the session yourself, you use the Symfony Session object. This allows for a more homogeneous use of the session and will help you if you later decide to modify some session settings like its duration or where it is saved. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session

Comment: I agree. Sessions in my example are created with this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessions. In the controller for your '/' route check if a flag is set in the session. If it is not, redirect to the '/welcome' page. In the controller for the '/welcome' route set this flag in the session.

Note that this will only last while the session is active. If you want a more permanent setting you will have to persist this to a database or something like that.